# grok multiple messages and process them with different tags

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok

I want to make a filter in Logstash(version 2.4) with different matches in the same grok.
I would like to add different tags depending on the match. 
Basically, I receive three different message pattern:
"##MAGIC##%message"
"##REAL##%message"
"%message"
I am trying to do is:

```
 grok {
 match => {"message" => "##MAGIC##%{GREEDYDATA:magic_message}"}
 match => {"message" => "##REAL##%{GREEDYDATA:real_message}"}
 match => {"message" => "%{GREEDYDATA:basic_message}"}
 if [magic_message]{
    overwrite => [ "message"]  
    add_tag => ["Magic"]
 } else if [real_message]{
    overwrite => [ "message"]  
    add_tag => ["Real"]
 }else{
   overwrite => [ "message"]  
    add_tag => ["Basic"]
 }
```

But, I got this compile fails:

```
    The given configuration is invalid. Reason: Expected one of #, => at line 34, column 9 (byte 900) after filter {
  grok {
     match => {"message" => "##MAGIC##%{GREEDYDATA:magic_message}"}
     match => {"message" => "##REAL##%{GREEDYDATA:real_message}"}
     match => {"message" => "%{GREEDYDATA:basic_message}"}
     if  {:level=>:fatal}
```

Comment: Why the requirement to do it in the same grok?

Comment: Because I have three different patterns and if I do three grok, every not match of each grok will cause _grokparsefailure

Comment: Run one grok with overwrite and add_tag, and set the GPF to something like "my_grok_missed".  If that is found, remove it and run the second grok. If it's found again, remove it and run the third grok.

Comment: @AlainCollins is your suggestion in the comment better practice than the method in the accepted answer and why? Does one way perform better than the other?

Comment: @darkwing, performance-wise, they're probably about the same, unless overwrite is much faster than replace.  I think I liked keeping each case separate (each with it's own grok, overwrite, and add_tag), versus doing it in two different phases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The logstash configuration syntax does not work like this.

This should work better (under the assumption that you want to replace message by `magic_message`/`real_message`):

```
grok {
    match => {"message" => [ "##MAGIC##%{GREEDYDATA:magic_message}",
                             "##REAL##%{GREEDYDATA:real_message}", 
                             "%{GREEDYDATA:basic_message}"]}
}
if [magic_message] {
    mutate {
        replace => { "message" => "%{magic_message}" }
        add_tag => ["Magic"]
    }
} else if [real_message] {
    mutate {   
        replace => { "message" => "%{real_message}" }
        add_tag => ["Real"] 
    }
} else {
    mutate {
        add_tag => ["Basic"] 
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank @baudsp, I changed "copy" to "replace" and I add "%" just before my field, in order to use the value of the variable. I think that "copy" is not available in my logstash version

Comment: @MariaMontenegro Sorry for the copy/replace mistake, I found the copy option in the documentation of the 5.4 version.