# GROK patterns for java exception

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok, logstash-configuration

I have a couple of questions :

1. I tried to use a custom tag like mentioned in https://discuss.elastic.co/t/logstash-configuration-with-custom-patterns/141352 but could not get much help.
2. I want to match for multiple patterns like one for normal log and one for exception log.

   ```
   ^%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp} %{LOGLEVEL:level}\s*%{JAVACLASS:class}\.%{WORD:method}\s-\s%{GREEDYDATA:log}$
   ```
3. We also have java patterns that are inbuilt but i was unable to find them by search, so are they compiled and stored ? I wanted to add my patterns in the same file so that i don't get any issues.

Is there another way to get this done apart from writing in the patterns folder?

Comment: I configure java log parsing (and exception tagging) directly in logstash's config. Take a look at a blog post with example for Spring Boot and see if it helps: http://knes1.github.io/blog/2015/2015-08-16-manage-spring-boot-logs-with-elasticsearch-kibana-and-logstash.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I want to use `(^.+Exception: .+)|(^\s+at .+)|(^\s+... \d+ more)|(^\s*Caused by:.+)` pattern so that i can have new fields like Exception and causedBy so that i can later do a group by kinda thing. So can i put this pattern somewhere inline ? Please help.

Comment: It is possible to give multiple patterns to grok. It seems the syntax has changed since that blog post and new one is `grok { match => { "message" => [ ... ] }}` (e.g. you can supply a list of patterns inline). I'd try putting your exception pattern on before your regular pattern in the pattern list.

Comment: Apart from that as i said i want to split it up if possible please post the grok pattern

Comment: @Raghuveer, Did you get any solution for this?

Comment: You can add the patterns inline like `(?<atag>mygrokpattern)` this solved my issue

Answer (score 1):

I'm working with Elastic Stack 7.6.2.

### Concatenate stack trace lines into one log entry

I'm sending logs to Logstash through Filebeat. I have to configure Filebeat so it treats the whole stack trace as one entry. I'm using `multiline` as described in [Examples of multiline configuration](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/multiline-examples.html#_examples_of_multiline_configuration):

```
#filebeat.yml
filebeat:
  inputs:
    - type: log
      …
      multiline:
        pattern: '^[[:space:]]+(at|\.{3})[[:space:]]+\b|^Caused by:'
        match: after
output:
  logstash:
    hosts: ["logstash:5044"]
```

### Handle two types of log entries

In my `logstash.conf` file I have a filter matching against:

- a regular Spring Boot log entry (not covered here)
  e.g.:

```
    2020-05-12 08:31:26.530  INFO 10197 --- [SpringContextShutdownHook] o.s.s.c.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor           : Shutting down ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
```

- a Java exception
  e.g.:

```
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Exception message
        at in.keepgrowing.springbootlog4j2scaffolding.SpringBootLog4j2ScaffoldingApplication.main(SpringBootLog4j2ScaffoldingApplication.java:14) [classes/:?]
        at com.example.myproject.Author.getBookIds(Author.java:38)
        at com.example.myproject.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:14)
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.example.myproject.Book.getId(Book.java:22)
        at com.example.myproject.Author.getBookIds(Author.java:35)
        ... 1 more
```

Because I haven't listed multiple patterns in one `match`, every entry is being checked against both matches (I think the [`break_on_match`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-grok.html#plugins-filters-grok-break_on_match) is not working in this case). As a result the `_grokparsefailure` tag is added to all entries. To remove this tag I have to know that a particular entry was successfuly matched by one pattern - the `stacktrace` or `spring_boot_log` tag will be present in such a case. Therefore I can safely delete the `_grokparsefailure` tag for entries that have my tag:

```
# logstash.conf
…
filter {
    grok {
        match => { "message" => "%{JAVACLASS:exception}:\s%{GREEDYDATA:stacktrace}" }
        add_tag => [ "stacktrace" ]
        }
    grok {
        match => { "message" => "%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:log_timestamp}…" }
        add_tag => [ "spring_boot_log" ]
        }
    if "stacktrace" in [tags] or "spring_boot_log" in [tags] {
            mutate {
                remove_tag => ["_grokparsefailure"]
                }
    }
}
…
```

Below you can see the screenshot from my ElasticHQ showing how an example stack trace was parsed. There are two parts: `exception` and `stacktrace`, and my custom tag in the `tags` array:
[image]

Useful links:

- https://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/patterns
- https://discuss.elastic.co/t/is-there-a-way-to-tag-for-different-grok-matches/52785
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/46589940/7995881
- https://discuss.elastic.co/t/logstash-7-grok-filter-plugin-break-on-match-appears-to-be-broken/176578/6
- https://sematext.com/blog/handling-stack-traces-with-logstash/
- https://dzone.com/articles/using-multiple-grok-statements