# Is there a single grok pattern which could parse 2 different style of same system logs

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok

I have system logs of the type --

```
Apr 05 11:35:54 FNM00181600566-A control-path[20757]: 2019-04-05 11:35:54.168 [] [INFO] [com.command.CommandServiceVerticle|vert.x-eventloop-thread-3] [f0a447b9-cd28-4062-9635-8cebac682567] About to process Command com.contexts.eventprocessing.eventse

Apr 05 11:35:57 FNM00181600566-A xtremapp[99510]: Apr 05 11:35:57.242761 M [log_id:0][22884(23048 nb_truck_0_sym   0x7f9d108d61c0)]sym_query_select_mom_object:3010: JBOD enclosure object type, checking numbering against peer

Apr 05 11:35:55 FNM00181600566-A control-path[20757]: [INFO ] [REST] [external.rest.RequestValidationModule|vert.x-eventloop-thread-0] Validating GET request: /api/rest/level_session_volume_view?select=id,name,resource_type,family_id,source_appliance_id,destination_appliance_id,state,job_id,progress_percentage,automatic,operation_status,created_timestamp,last_sync_timestamp,estimated_completion_timestamp,rescan_hosts,recommendation_id
```

All of these 3 lines are in the same log file, but are very different from one another. Can we use ELK to extract the contents of the log file using a single grok pattern? If there is any other filter I could use, please let me know.

I tried the grok filter pattern :

```
**%{SYSLOGBASE} *%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601} *(?<extra1>[\s*\[*\w*\]*\s]+) *%{LOGLEVEL} *(?<extra2>[\s*\w*\]*\s]+) *\[%{NOTSPACE:component}\] *%{GREEDYDATA:message}**
```

But it only works for some of the log lines.

Comment: You can also use more than one pattern in the same grok filter. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46589940/6113627) for an example of this

Comment: Or you could use a `if [message] =~ // { grok {...} } else if [message] =~ // { grok {...} } else { grok {...} }` form. See https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/config-examples.html#using-conditionals

Comment: how are you exporting the logs to es ?  are you using filebeats ?